# Что будет находится в памяти при преобразовании данного выражения - Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
SNAPI_POWER_MODE = '\x0b\x81\x02\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

qt говорит что это строка, я полагаю что можно рассматривать это как массив, вроде все понятно, но тогда что происходит здесь ?

```
SNAPI_COMMAND_1 = '\r@\x00\x06\x00\x06\x02\x00N$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

или например тут?

```
SNAPI_BEEP = '\r@\x00\t\x00\t\x05\x00\x17pX\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

эти строки приходят на вход такой функции

```
def set_param(self, _data, _timeout=100, _exception=True): 
    byte_array = bytearray() 
    parameter = _data[0] 
    byte_array.append(2) 
    byte_array.append(parameter) 
    send_value = ('').join(map(chr, byte_array)) 
    send_value = struct.unpack('>H', send_value)[0]
    self.usb_send(33, 9, send_value, 0, _data.__str__(), _timeout, _exception)
```

что в итоге будет передано?

Comment: Это всё строки. Для того чтобы создать строку байтов, нужно сделать так: `b'...'`.

Comment: если это строки, то как мне их очеловечить? я хочу перенести их в С++                                     ,  и если это просто строки то для чего столько нулей?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что эти переменные имеют тип данных `str` (строка). Не факт, что их можно преобразовать в текст.

Comment: эти строки приходят на вход такой функции `def set_param(self, _data, _timeout=100, _exception=True):
        byte_array = bytearray()
        parameter = _data[0]
        byte_array.append(2)
        byte_array.append(parameter)
        send_value = ('').join(map(chr, byte_array))
        send_value = struct.unpack('>H', send_value)[0]
        self.usb_send(33, 9, send_value, 0, _data.__str__(), _timeout, _exception)`                                 что в итоге будет передано?

Comment: @DowJhob управляющая последовательность байтов будет передана.

Comment: как мне ее записать на С?

Comment: Скорее всего код для Python2, потому что под Python3 код `parameter = _data[0] ; byte_array.append(parameter) ` вызовет ошибку `'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Для Python3 вместо строк на вход должны подаваться наборы байт (добавить `b` перед открывающимися кавычками строк). На Си это будут массивы `unsigned char` или массивы `uint8_t`.

Comment: *"я хочу перенести их в С++"* шестнадцатеричные escape-последовательности типа `data = b'\x0b\x81\x02\x00'` поддерживаются и в C++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: \x17pX вот это место разве поддерживается С? опытнным путем я уже выяснил что читать \x17 + 'p' + 'X' собственно это меня и интересовало

Comment: @DowJhob, вполне поддерживается.

Comment: А поясните что за магия происходит при вычислении `send_value ` ?

Comment: могу ли я заменить все эти распаковки на      `quint16 send_value = 0x200 + _data[0];` ?